# Converting a C++ library to a .so / .dll shared library

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jna, integrate

I am using the GRT library which is written in C++ and I want to integrate that with Java using JNA. To do that I want to make that a shared library (.dll/.so) . But I have no idea, how to do this.

Here is the link to GRT library.

https://github.com/nickgillian/grt/tree/master/GRT

I just want to call the methods from this C++ library.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://github.com/nickgillian/grt/tree/master/build :

```
$ cmake .. -DBUILD_STATIC_LIB=OFF
$ make
```

There should then be a `libgrt.so` file somewhere in the build directory.

Comment: Thanks moosigin3space... I just saw it.. my bad.. :-)